# Application-level onPause

Tags: android, onpause

I know that Android doesn't have an Application-level onPause the way an Activity has an onPause, but it looks like I need a similar functionality.  I asked a (dumb) question awhile ago (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508301/checking-the-manner-in-which-an-activity-has-been-reanimated) and realized that onPause/onResume will give me what I'm looking for:  The ability to know if the Activity has been relegated to the background (either via the Home button, opening a different app, the phone sleeping, etc.).

The trouble is, onPause also fires in an Activity as I go from one Activity in my App to another.  So I'm heading down the road of finding EVERY SINGLE way a user can go from Activity to Activity in my app (and there are anywhere from 15 to 25 of those) and setting a flag right before each user-initiated Activity switch.  Then in onResume I'm checking that flag and if it's X, I know that it was a user-initiated onResume.  If the flag is Y, I know that it's a result of the Home button being pressed, the phone sleeping, etc.).

This just seems like a big messy kludge.  Is there a better way?

(I add this to help, not to confuse:  My goal is to have a (very annoying, I know) passcode screen that pops up any time the app goes away from the foreground for any reason (even screen sleep).  I planned to use onPause/onResume to check when to pop the Passcode activity, but onPause fires every time I change Activities and therefore I need to add more.)

Comment: you want to show passcode activity when user press back key or home key?

Comment: not back key.  not even JUST home key.  I want the passcode screen to pop anytime the app leaves the foreground or the screen goes dark due to timing out.  I figured onPause/onResume would work for this (and it does within a single activity) but I can't solely rely on onPause because onPause also fires when I go from Activity to Activity in my App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps like Pinnacle Locker do something similar--I believe they intercept an Intent for specific packages, and thus are fired whenever the system switches to an app, but not when the user changes screens between apps.

I may be misunderstanding you, but another approach would be to turn your approach around: whenever you change from one screen to the other inside an app, you are either launching an Intent or finish()ing (such as when the user presses the back button), right?

Then you could set a flag in your internal Intents, and whenever you directly call finish() or when onBackPressed() is called in your apps you could set a similar flag. If that flag is not set when onResume() runs in your app, then you could show the lockscreen.

Comment: This seems intriguing.  Instead of setting a flag in all of my activities at any point where the user initiates another activity, I could create a global class that handles Intent changes and set the flag there.  I'd have to update my code everywhere to replace the standard startActivity(intent), but that should be less work than the approach I was going to take.  I'll start digging into this, but I'm worried I'm going to run into context issues...

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer your question, but perhaps as an alternate approach, could you make an activity base class that does the flag management and have all your activities inherit from that? You could even do something like set a timeout of, say, 5 seconds between one activity's onPause and another activity's onResume to decide that you were doing an out-of-app switch instead of an in-app switch, although if you just have a utility function that you call from your activity base class for initiating an activity change, that still vastly reduces the surface area of where you have to keep track of things.

Answer (score 0):

You should combine the onPause() function with application visibility status and process further if your application is not visible. Following code might help:

```
private boolean isVisible(String app) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager
                .getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
            if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_VISIBLE) {
                Log.i("Foreground App", appProcess.processName);
                if (app.equalsIgnoreCase(appProcess.processName)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Again this might not fit in your current scenario entirely.

Comment: This looks good, too.  I'll give it a shot and check back here to reward the best solution for my problem with a magical green checkmark.